# Open sets under weak*-topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let M be the set of all Borel probability measures on $S=[0,1]$ and denote by $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on S. According to the Lebesgue decomposition theorem, every $\mu\in M$ can be decomposed as $$\mu=\mu_a+\mu_s$$ where $\mu_s$ is singular with respect to $\lambda$ and $\mu_a$ is absolutely continuous. Furthermore, define a function $U:M\rightarrow[0,1]$ by $$U(\mu):=\int x\mu_a(dx)$$.Based on this function, one defines a preference relation on $M$ with $$\mu\prec\sigma 
 \text{ iff: } U(\mu)<U(\sigma),\forall \mu,\sigma\in M$$.

Now endowed the space $M$ with the weak*-topology, one wishes to define the continuity of a preference relation:

A preference relation on $M$ with weak*-topology is continuous iff the following sets: $$\mathscr B(\mu)^{+}:=\{\sigma\in M| \mu\prec\sigma\}$$ $$\mathscr B(\mu)^{-}:=\{\sigma\in M| \sigma\prec\mu\}$$
is open under weak*-topology.

**Question**: I know that this preference relation is not continuous, (i.e. $\mathscr B(\mu)^{+}$ and $\mathscr B(\mu)^{-}$ is not open.) How can I see that $\mathscr B(\mu)^{+}$ and $\mathscr B(\mu)^{-}$ induced by $U(\mu)$ is not open under weak*-topology?

**Edit:** My approach: Using the fact, that the set of simple probability measures $M_s$ (simple is defined as that a measure can be written as a finite sum of dirac measures $\delta_{x_i}$: $\mu\in M_s\rightarrow \mu=\sum_{i=0}^{i=N}\alpha_i\delta_{x_i}$) is dense in $M$ under the weak*-topology（I assume that the underlying space is Polish）, I can find a sequence of $\mu_n\in M_s$ such that $\mu_n\rightarrow\mu\in M$. However, we know that the Dirac-measure is singular to Lebesgue measure, therefore $U(\mu_n)=0,\forall \mu_n\in M_s$.

Now consider an absolute continuous positive measure $\sigma\in M$ and construct a sequence of simple probability measure $\sigma_n$. As $\sigma$ is a positive measure, $U(\sigma)>0=U(\sigma_n),\forall \sigma_n\in M_s$. Hence pick a point from $\sigma_n$ and denote $x_0$. Consider the set $\mathscr B(\delta_{x_0})^{+}:=\{\sigma'\in M| \delta_{x_0}\prec\sigma'\}$, $\sigma \in \mathscr B(\delta_{x_0})^{+}$. If $\mathscr B(\delta_{x_0})^{+}$ is open under weak*-topology, then there exist an N such that $\sigma_n\in\mathscr B(\delta_{x_0})^{+}, \forall n>N$. However, $U(\sigma_n)=0,\forall n\in \Bbb N$ and $\notin B(\delta_{x_0})^{+}$. Therefore, the set cannot be open.

Does it make sense?

Comment: So we see $M$ as the dual of $C(X)$, so its weak-star topology is the smallest one that makes all maps $\mu \to \int f d\mu$ continuous, for all fixed $ f \in C([0,1])$ right?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes that's right. I think the $f$ is even bounded as the dual space contains only bounded functionals.